# RStudio Open Source not accepting input

Tags: rstudio

I'm not sure if this is the right place to address this, but here goes...

I've just installed RStudio (v1.3.959) on my Windows 10 laptop. If I leave the window on the laptop screen, all is well, but if I drag the window on to one of my external monitors it stops accepting keyboard input or responding to menu selections *until* I move the window back to the monitor screen.

I've never seen this behaviour in *any* other software.

To be clear. This is **not** a new setup; I've been using this configration of hardware, without problems, for *months.* This problem *only* exists when using RStudio.

Is there something wrong with my installation or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the external monitor. monitor is not configured to accept inputs from some I/O devices.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq Really? I've had this setup for ages and I use it for Office, Visual Studio, and dozens of other apps.

Comment: Does the issue also happen if you open R on its own?

Comment: @Phil, if you mean when I just fire up R.exe in a cmd window, then no. Likewise, if you mean if I run rGui.exe, no; it works just fine.

The problem is _only_ with RStudio

Comment: I'd file an issue on their GH repo.